# Conditional Calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a calculation that I'm doing in SQL with the following:

```
SELECT 
    round(sum(total_size) / (1024*1024), 2) 'Total (PB)' ,
    round(sum(keep_size) / (1024*1024), 2) 'Keep (PB)' ,
    round(sum(remove_size) / (1024*1024), 2) 'Remove (PB)' 
FROM (
  SELECT
    case when dedupe_status='K' then path when dedupe_status='R' then null when dedupe_status='G' then group_super end as g_key,
    round(sum(file_size), 2) total_size,
    case when dedupe_status='R' then round(sum(file_size), 2) when dedupe_status='K' then 0 when dedupe_status='G' then round(sum(file_size) - file_size, 2) end remove_size,
    case when dedupe_status='R' then 0 when dedupe_status='K' then file_size when dedupe_status='G' then round(sum(file_size) - (sum(file_size) - file_size), 2) end keep_size
    from dedupe__df group by g_key
  ) clean_list
```

I've only included this for reference. Here is my dataframe where I'm trying to do the same calculation within pandas. Here is the data-frame I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
    {'dedupe_status': 'R', 'size': 134, 'dedupe_key': 'g_149'},
    {'dedupe_status': 'K', 'size': 101, 'dedupe_key': 'g9'},
    {'dedupe_status': 'G', 'size': 101, 'dedupe_key': 'x09'},
    {'dedupe_status': 'G', 'size': 405, 'dedupe_key': 'xx01'},
    {'dedupe_status': 'G', 'size': 4, 'dedupe_key': 'x09'},
    {'dedupe_status': 'G', 'size': 1405, 'dedupe_key': 'xx01'},
    {'dedupe_status': 'G', 'size': 401, 'dedupe_key': 'xx01'},
])
```

I want to get a result with three values, the `Total Size`, `Remove Size`, and `Keep Size`. Here is how they are calculated:

- `Total`: easy, just sum up all the size.
- `Keep`: if the status is `K` (**Keep**), add up the size. If the status is `R` (**Remove**), skip it, if the status is `G` (**Group**) then group on the `dedupe_key` and keep **only one** of the sizes (it doesn't matter which, if simplest you can grab `first` or `min`). In other words, when the value is `G`, it means all elements are a duplicate in that group and we only need to keep one of them.
- `Remove`: `Total` - `Keep`

With the above values, we would have:

```
field           value            # comments
Total           2551             # df['size'].sum()
Keep            607              # 101 (K) + 101 (G: x09) + 405(G: xx01)
Remove          1944             # 134 (R) + 4 (G: x08) + 1405+401 (G: xx01)
```

So far I have:

```
>>> df['new_key'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'R' if row.dedupe_status == 'R' else row.dedupe_key, axis=1)
>>> df.groupby('new_key').agg(total=('size', 'sum'))
```

How would I do the rest in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `np.where` to find those `Keep`:

```
mask = np.where(df.dedupe_status.eq('R') | 
                (df.duplicated(['dedupe_status', 'dedupe_key']) &
                 df.dedupe_status.eq('G') 
                ),
                'Remove', 'Keep')
                
                

ret = df.groupby(mask)['size'].sum()
ret.loc['Total'] = ret.sum()
```

Output:

```
Keep       607
Remove    1944
Total     2551
Name: size, dtype: int64
```

Comment: great, and the easy part too (Total?)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new df1 to summarize the inforamtion as you have suggested. At the end you can use iloc to to select just the first row and last three columns and then use `.T` to transpose the dataframe:

```
df1 = (df.assign(Total=df['size'].sum())
         .assign(Keep=df[df['dedupe_status'] == 'K']['size'].sum()
                 + df[df['dedupe_status'] == 'G'].groupby('dedupe_key')['size'].min().sum()))
df1 = df1.assign(Remove=df1['Total'] - df1['Keep']).iloc[0,-3:].T
df1

Total     2551
Keep       506 #101 + 4 + 401
Remove    2045
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: it looks like a great solution but the numbers seem off...

Comment: @David542 I used 'min' - you said any value could be returned? Maybe I didn't understand.

Comment: yea that works, but how did you get the number `105`? I don't see that as a file size.

Comment: @David542 101 + 4

Comment: aah I understand now, I will update my answer. It sounds like you want one from each Group of G?

Comment: yea, to keep one per group if the status == '`G`.